# Helper method not being recognised - possibly because namespaced?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have an `Admin` namespace, and a `sessions` controller within it.

There was also a `admin/sessions_helper.rb` made when I generated the controller, so I've been putting some methods in that, however I don't seem to be able to call them. Is this down to the namespace?

**Error**

```
undefined local variable or method `sign_out' for #<Admin::SessionsController:0x007fe2b2f55680>

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to admin_path
  end
end
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::SessionsController < AdminController

  ...

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to admin_path
  end
end
```

**admin/sessions_helper.rb**

```
module Admin::SessionsHelper
  ...

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
end
```

Note that I'm not including the helper anywhere, because in the docs it says that [all helpers are included by default](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html).

Answer (score 3):

Helpers are not available in the controller. Helpers are designed to be mixed into the view context.

There are workarounds to make the helper available to both the view and the controller, but it should actually make sense. The `sign_out` method you defined would not make sense at all in the view.

I suggest you to define it in the `AdminController` (that looks to be the base controller all admin controller inherits from).

```
module AdminController
  ...

  private

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
end
```

Be sure to flag it as private or Rails could potentially use it as a controller action.

Comment: Ok great, thank you. Do you know why Michael Hartl does it differently in his [tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-a_working_sign_in_method)?

Comment: In the tutorial he defines the `SessionsHelper` then he mixes the helper in the Controller. In that way the methods inside the helper will be available to both view and controller. As I said, sometimes it makes sense, in your case it doesn't because the `sign_out` would not make a lot of sense to be called from a view.

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to call helper methods from a controller without including the module is with [view_context](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Rendering.html#method-i-view_context):

```
class Admin::SessionsController < AdminController
  def destroy
    view_context.sign_out
    redirect_to admin_path
  end
end
```

But I agree with @simone-carletti, this doesn't feel like a helper method.